# Custom button in Windows 8.1 app

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a requirement to create a button in a Windows 8.1 app which has an icon and a text label.  The icon will be a symbol from Segoe UI Symbols and the text label will be Segoe UI Semibold at a smaller text size.

I want to be able to reuse the button in different places within the app, using different icons and text labels.

How show I go about this?  I could create a button and then edit the ContentPresenter to have a horizontally oriented stack panel with two TextBlocks, but then how could I reuse this? And how could I change the text in the two different text blocks?

Should I create a separate custom control with separate dependency properties for each of the textblock strings?  I'm interested in hearing what you would do.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a simple `Style`. To make it easy, I would base it off the standardized `AppBarButton` style. You can format it to whatever size you want (I have done something similar to make a larger button or one with text on the side).

Have the main icon simply be a `ContentPresenter` which binds to the `Content` using a `TemplateBinding`. Make sure to set the `FontFamily` to `Segoe UI Symbol`. Have the text label pull from `AutomationProperties.Name`, similar to how the `AppBarButton` style does.

Then, whenever you want to use this just do:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyCustomButtonStyle}"
        Content="&#xe000;" // Where "000" is replaced by the number of the icon you wish to use.
        AutomationProperties.Name="Text Label"/>
```

This should be extensible and easily reproducible to whatever location you need. When copying over the `AppBarButton` style, I suggest removing the artificial size limits (specifically the width of the main content `Grid`). I *do* suggest either giving the Text Label a fixed size or having it pull its size from the specified parent `Width`, so that it will `Wrap` correctly.

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Comment: Hi there, the AppBarButtonStyle is deprecated in 8.1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662743.aspx  But thanks for the tip, I'll look into how I can pull the text label text from AutomationProperties.Name.

Comment: The style is indeed deprecated, but you can still pull the one that was used in 8 and copy it right in. Nobody says you can't!

Answer (score 2):

Are you desiring to create something like for an AppBar?  Take a look at AppBarButton and the style/types it supports.  In Windows 8.1 we added some things around SymbolIcon specifically.  Since you basically want two pieces of 'content' for your style you'll have to re-purpose one property (unless you create a custom control which doesn't sound needed for this scenario).  Using AutiomationProperties.Name for the visible label is a good idea because it will also help with accessibility by default for those users.

Investigate the style for AppBarButton to get you started.

Comment: I have tried creating a new Style BasedOn="AppBarButtonStyle", but this style is deprecated in 8.1.  Plus there's no StandardStyles.xaml for me to inspect anymore.  I'm basically trying to creating a button inside a left pane nav bar that looks a bit like the Twitter app's nav buttons. thanks for your help, I'll explore further.  Good to know this isn't a custom control scenario, as it seemed like overkill.

Comment: I found my solution: use a Radio button and then create a custom style for that with a control template.  Perfect.  I have these buttons in a 'navigation' user control on a standard page, so now all I need to do is figure out how I can bind which of the radio buttons is checked, to the page's view model. I think the solution will be a dependency property on the navigation control bound to a INotifyPropertyChange property on the VM of the main page. hmmm... getting there! :-)